# difference between @apollo/client , apollo-client and apollo boost

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-boost

I am implementing using `@apollo/client`, but i do not see any complete example of `@apollo/client` with `react`.
If i search i get example with  `apollo-client` and `apollo boost`.

**What is the difference between all 3.**
I understand `@apollo/client` is the new version of all. **Where can i get complete example of `@apollo/client` with `react` application?**

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloLink, createHttpLink, defaultDataIdFromObject } from '@apollo/client';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloLink } from 'apollo-boost';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- apollo-boost

Apollo Boost includes some packages that we think are essential to developing with Apollo Client. Here's what's in the box:

- `apollo-client`: Where all the magic happens
- `apollo-cache-inmemory`: Our recommended cache
- `apollo-link-http`: An Apollo Link for remote data fetching
- `apollo-link-error`: An Apollo Link for error handling
- `graphql-tag`: Exports the gql function for your queries & mutations

The awesome thing about Apollo Boost is that you don't have to set any of this up yourself! Just specify a few options if you'd like to use these features and we'll take care of the rest. For a full list of available options, please refer to the Apollo Boost configuration options documentation.

see [What's in Apollo Boost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-boost#whats-in-apollo-boost)

- apollo-client

The old version(below 3.x) apollo client

- @apollo/client

The latest version(3.x+) apollo client published as [Scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/scope.html)

Check the official [get started example](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-started-coinbase-client-73r10)

Comment: i am getting this error.  React Hook "useQuery" is called in function "getData" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks. I am using same package.json file from the example link. I ran the exmaple link you gave, it works fine. I created the app using yarn create-reactapp. is that something causing this issue?

Answer (score 14):

Just to add to the already posted answer for anyone wondering if they should still be using Boost.

From the docs:

> The Apollo Boost project is now retired, because Apollo Client 3.0
> provides a similarly straightforward setup. We recommend removing all
> apollo-boost dependencies and modifying your ApolloClient constructor
> as needed.